# Runtime Error with Unity Plugins (startActivity from outside of an Activity..)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I'm implementing two plugins in my unity project. First plugin is a [live wallpaper](https://github.com/0xBFE1A8/Unity3dAndroidLiveWallpaper) which contain the main activity. The second plugin is a [native sharing](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeShare). 
What I did is I got the context reference from the first plugin which contain the main activity:

```
    public static Context getContext() 
{
     instance.startActivity(myIntent);
     return instance;
}
```

In unity script

```
Main_Context = appClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getContext");
```

and then I use the **Main_Context** reference to call a sharing function in the second plugin

```
new NativeShare().AddFile(Application.persistentDataPath + "/img Shot.png").SetSubject(" Image Share").SetText("").Share(Main_Context);
```

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the  
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

So it seems that I some how need to add this line in the second plugin just before the startactivity() call

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Is there an easier way to solve this error without editing an already compiled plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so it turns out the live wallpaper project and its Plugins extend the standard `UnityPlayerActivity` class, which means the `currentActivity` has been overridden and `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer` no longer exist. So instead of getting the `currentActivity` like this:

```
    private static AndroidJavaObject Context
{
    get
    {
        if( m_context == null )
        {
            using( AndroidJavaObject unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass( "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer" ) )
            {
                m_context = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>( "currentActivity" );
            }
        }

        return m_context;
    }
}
```

we can use the plug-ins that extended and override the standard `UnityPlayerActivity` class:

```
    private static AndroidJavaObject Context
{
    get
    {
        if( m_context == null )
        {
            using( AndroidJavaObject unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass( "ulw.ulw.ulw.UnityPlayerActivity" ) )
            {
                m_context = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>( "activity" );
            }
        }

        return m_context;
    }
```

Now all of the added plugins can coexist with the live wallpaper project and its Plugins.